# How to upgrade from iOS 14 to 15, NOT 16+?

Tags: iphone, ios, software-update, upgrade, versions

I cannot “upgrade” my iPhone to iOS 16 for [reasons](https://forums.macrumors.com/threads/those-on-mojave-or-older-dont-upgrade-to-ios-16.2358574/).

But I would like to at least go from 14 to 15 if that is possible. I have read that [15 is okay](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/253259965?answerId=256101542022#256101542022).

Google has this to say:

---

In response to **How do I upgrade my iPhone from iOS 14 to iOS 15?**

> **Go to Settings > General**, then tap Software Update. If you see more than one software update option available, choose the one you
> want to install. Tap Install Now. If you see Download and Install
> instead, tap it to download the update, enter your passcode, then tap Install Now.

<sup>Apr 12, 2023 [Source](https://support.apple.com/en-gb/HT204204)</sup>

---

In response to **Can I update to iOS 15 not 16?**

> Just choose the version you want to install and wait until the update
> process finishes. If you really don't want to install iOS 16, you can
> disable automatic updates on your device. Of course, keep in mind that
> Apple may keep iOS 15 updated with security enhancements for a limited
> time.

<sup>Sep 12, 2022 [Source](https://9to5mac.com/2022/09/12/ios-16-optional-ota-update-ios-15/)</sup>

---

I also looked at what others have discussed on reddit regarding **[How to update iPhone to a specific iOS](https://www.reddit.com/r/iphone/comments/103mwl3/how_to_update_iphone_to_a_specific_ios/)**, but it seems inconclusive.

Is there a way to at least upgrade by one version, or am I stuck?

The only option I am seeing is for iOS 16:

[image]

Comment: Might be easier to run Mojave in a VM for your old applications, and upgrade the Mac to a more recent version.

Comment: @nohillside Thank you for the suggestion. I'm not sure yet if that can be a solution for me, but [I'm looking into it now](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT208891).

Comment: I have no problems at all with Mojave & iOS 16. https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/463410/can-itunes-on-mojave-backup-ios-16-5-16-6